# SQL join combine with condition

Tags: sql, if-statement, join, conditional-statements

Please how to achieve following result from this data?

(I am trying to combine join with conditions but still with some unwanted rows.)

Input is in one table only:

```
ID    IN    OUT
-----------------
 1    6:00  null
 2    7:11  null
 2    null  16:30
 3    null  19:00
```

Output (a view) should combine same IDs so the result will looks like:

```
ID    IN    OUT
------------------
1     6:00  null
2     7:11  16:30
3     null  19:00
```

Comment: Can there be more than 2 of the same id?

Comment: Thank You, the solution consists from 2 steps:

1. normalize the data - split them into three distinct views (INs only, OUTs only and combined INs & OUTs)

2. UNION ALL these 3 views into 4h one

Answer (score 0):

You can try to achieve this with a CTE as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE #data
(
    Id int not null,
    inTime varchar(10) null,
    outTime varchar(10) null
)

 INSERT INTO #data VALUES 
  (1,    '6:00', null),
  (2 ,   '7:11', null),
  (2 ,   null, '16:30'),
  (3 ,   null, '19:00')


WITH combinedTable AS (
   SELECT
    Id,
    MAX(inTime) AS A,
    MAX(outTime) AS B
FROM #data
GROUP BY Id
HAVING MAX(2) = MIN(2)
    AND MAX(3) = MIN(3)
)
  SELECT *
  FROM combinedTable
  UNION ALL
  SELECT *
  FROM #data
  WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM combinedTable)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following can serve the purpose:
1. Have a table with ID and IN where IN is not equal to null:

```
(select ID, IN from table where In ne NULL()) as tableA
```

O/P would be:

```
ID    IN    
 1    6:00
 2    7:11
```

2.Have a table with ID and OUT where OUT is not equal to null:

```
(select ID, OUT from table where OUT ne NULL()) as tableB
```

O/P would be:

```
ID   OUT
 2  16:30
 3  19:00
```

3.Outer Join the two tables:

```
select tableA.ID,tableA.IN, tableB.OUT 
from table as tableA

outer full join

select ID,OUT from table as tableB
On tableA.ID=tableB.ID and tableA.IN ne Null() and tableB.OUT ne NULL()
```

Output will be the desired output:

```
 ID    IN    OUT
1     6:00  null
2     7:11  16:30
3     null  19:00
```